# Adding tag dynamically by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I use jquery to add tag dynamically, but I face some problems. I can remove the tags in original code, however, I can't remove the tag which is added by jquery.

Another question is how could I avoid adding duplicated tag (same value)? Many thanks!

```
<div id='searchTerm' class='searchTerm'>
    <span><b>U.S.A</b><a class="remove" href="#"></a></span>
    <span><b>H.K.</b><a class="remove" href="#"></a></span>
</div>

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#addTag').click(function() {
        var html='';
        html += '<span><b>' + $("#newTag").val() + '</b><a class="remove" href="#"></a></span>';
        $('#searchTerm').append(html);
    });
    $('.remove').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use <kbd>[**on()**](https://api.jquery.com/on/)</kbd> for the tags added dynamically

```
$(document).on('click','.remove',function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: @Eric, .click() will simply apply the click event for the items found in DOM at the time of loading. They will not be invoked for dynamically added elements. However, with `on()` you can attach the `click` event at the document level but with a specific selectors.

Comment: But if I use `$('.remove').on('click', function({$(this).parent().remove();});` to implement the event, the new tags could not be deleted. So the reason might be using `$(document)`?

Comment: @Eric, basically `$(document)` you are asking a document to take care of listening for `.remove` selectors. In your code, you are asking the current `.remove` elements to take care. But they will not take care of the dynamic items

Comment: I got it! Thank you for kindly reply! Have a nice day :)

Comment: Do you have any suggestion about how to avoid adding duplicated tag?

Comment: @Eric, `$('#searchTerm').find('b').each(function(){if($(this).text()=='yourTagName'){alert('Exists'); return;}  });` Just checking before we add it. If it exists, skip adding it by return statement